# Upload Video using new FileReference class

Tags: actionscript-3, video, arrays, flv, filereference

With the changes to the FileReferance rules for FP10 it is now possible to upload a local file directly to the client side application without the server roundtrip.

For loading an image I use this code to deal with the ByteArray:

```
private function completeHandler(e:Event):void
    {

        loader = new Loader();

        var f:FileReference = FileReference(e.target);
        var d:ByteArray = null;

        try {
            d = f["data"];
        } catch (er:Error) {
            trace(er.message)
        }

        if (d != null) {
            loader.loadBytes(d);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoadedListener);
        }

    }
```

The loadBytes method interprets the bytearray and puts it into a Bitmap object.

The Loader Class only works for jpg, gif, png & swf. Say I wanted the user to be able to upload and view a flv, could I somehow plug the data into a NetStream object (or something!)? I would like to avoid uploading the flv.

rur

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't... NetStream is probably the worse, most outdated, and ugliest class in Flash (see NetStream::play2 xD)... It really amazes me how Flash is the dominant video platform on the internet with such a crappy video handler.